# Drawing a subregion of a BitmapSource

Tags: wpf, image, bitmapsource

I'm creating a level editor in WPF for a 2D tile-based game. I'm trying to figure out the best way to load the tileset `Image` file and render each tile in the appropriate location to reconstruct the map.

Currently, I'm loading the `Image` as a `BitmapSource`, and I'm deriving from the `Canvas` class for the control that displays the map. I'm overriding the `OnRender` method so I can get a `DrawingContext`. However, `DrawingContext.DrawImage` doesn't appear to have an appropriate overload that draws only a subrect of an image; it looks like I have to draw the entire image.

What should I use if I want to draw subrects of an `Image` onto a `Canvas`? Or should I be using something other than a `Canvas`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
{
    BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();
    source.BeginInit();
    source.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/YourProject;component/YourImage.jpg");
    source.SourceRect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    source.EndInit();

    dc.DrawImage(source, Rect.Parse("0, 0, 200, 200"));
    base.OnRender(dc);
}
```

The property that does this for you is [**BitmapImage.SourceRect**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.sourcerect.aspx).